# How can I solve ' context provider is not a route component ' error in react?

Tags: reactjs

I' am trying to fetch data from remote api in react and for this I decided to use context api but I cant use context api. Actually I think I did it right. When the browser is opened, a blank screen comes up, it should not be like this. React does not show any errors either, but when I open the console in the browser, the following errors appear. What's the problem?
Have you encountered a problem like this before?

**My Errors in console**

```
Uncaught Error: [ProductContextProvider] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

the above error occurred in the <Routes> component:

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import LoginPage from './Components/LoginPage'
import SignUpPage from './Components/SignUpPage'
import Home from './Components/Home';
import ProductList from './Components/ProductList'
import ProductContextProvider from './Contexts/ProductContext';
function App() {




  return (

    
      <div id='nav'>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-warning">
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <NavLink to="/" >Home  </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/LoginPage" >Login </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/SignUpPage" >Sign Up  </NavLink> 
              
          </ul>
        </nav>


        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/LoginPage" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="/SignUpPage" element={<SignUpPage />} />
            <ProductContextProvider>
            <Route path="/ProductList" element={<ProductList />} />
            </ProductContextProvider>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>

    
  );

}

export default App;
```

**productcontext.js**

```
import { createContext,useState,useEffect} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

export const ProductContext = createContext([])  

const ProductContextProvider = (props) =>{
    
   
    const [product,SetCategories] = useState([]);
 
    const url = 'http://localhost:64082/api/products'
  
    const fetchData = () => {
      axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          SetCategories(response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
      }, [])


    return(
        <ProductContext.Provider value={{product}}>
            {props.children}
        </ProductContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default ProductContextProvider
```

**ProductList.js**

```
import ProductContext from '../Contexts/ProductContext';
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Product from './Product'


export default function ProductList() {
  
   const products = useContext(ProductContext)

    return (
        
    
        <table className='table table-striped table-hover'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product ID</th>
                    <th>product is offerable</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Product Description</th>
                    <th>Product is sold</th>
                    <th>Category ID</th>
                   
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    products.map((product) =>(
                        <tr key={product.id}>
                            <Product product={product} />
                        </tr>
                    ))
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

**Product.js**

```
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ProductContext } from '../Contexts/ProductContext';
import { Button, Modal, OverlayTrigger, Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap';



const Product = ({ product }) => {

    const { dispatch } = useContext(ProductContext);

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        handleClose();
    }, [product])

    return (

        <>

            <td>{product.productId}</td>
            <td>{product.isOfferable}</td>
            <td>{product.productName}</td>
            <td>{product.productDescription}</td>
            <td>{product.isSold}</td>
            <td>{product.categoryId}</td>
            <td>
                <OverlayTrigger
                    overlay={
                        <Tooltip id={`tooltip-top`}>
                            Edit
                        </Tooltip>
                    }>
                    <button onClick={handleShow} className="btn text-warning btn-act" data-toggle="modal"><i className="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></button>
                </OverlayTrigger>
                <OverlayTrigger
                    overlay={
                        <Tooltip id={`tooltip-top`}>
                            Delete
                        </Tooltip>
                    }>
                <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'remove_employee', id: product.id})} className="btn text-danger btn-act" data-toggle="modal"><i className="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></button>
                </OverlayTrigger>
            </td>

            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header className="modal-header" closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>
                        Update product
                </Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    {/* <EditForm theProduct={product} /> */}
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                        Close Modal
                </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </>

    )
}

export default Product;
```

Comment: Try wrapping the _<ProductList />_ component with the context provider instead of the whole route itself. As the error suggests, only <Route /> components are accepted inside the <Routes /> component.

Comment: How can I do that ? can you explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, only  components can be used inside . Since you are trying to wrap one of the routes inside a context provider, essentially, you are passing in the context provider as a child to the parent  component. Therefore, to pass in the context provider, you should do the following in your App.js file.

```
<Route path="/ProductList" element={
    <ProductContextProvider>
        <ProductList />
    </ProductContextProvider>
}
/>
```